# How to use composer in a localwp project?

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

I’m a newby on using composer, git, etc, in fact I’ve never used them, but I need the [Spaces API PHP library](https://github.com/SociallyDev/Spaces-API) (which requires composer) for my project.

Since LocalWP includes composer, could anyone tell me in detail how to integrate it into my project?

The tutorials I've found are not ment for LocalWP specific case. All of them teach u how to install composer, but since LocalWP has it already, I don't know how to apply it to my project.

**My System Details:**

- LocalWP latest version
- Windows 10 Pro
- Chrome
- VS Code

Comment: I can't give you full details on how to do it, and that would be out of scope for this site anyway, but I can tell you that for WordPress you'd want that library to be included either in your theme or a custom plugin that you create. For both of those options there's nothing specific to LocalWP that you need to worry about, you can follow the official WP guides or most tutorials for how to do that.

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas, thanks for answering. I do have the library in my custom wp plugin, but how do I initiate it so I can use the needed class from it? I've been trying to load it via require_once(dirname( __FILE__ ).'/library/Spaces-API-master/SpacesAPI/Spaces.php'), but doesn't seems to work. Could u point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: If you've installed the library in your plugin using composer, from your plugin entry file you'd just use `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` and PHP will take care of the rest. You'll still need to qualify your usage of those items, either through a `use` statement at the top of your code, or through fully-qualified names such as `new \A\B\C()`

Comment: I asume that by installing the plugin using composer u mean via the terminal 'composer install' or something like that. No, I've just downloaded the library and pasted it into my custom plugin, but I asume it doesn't work that way. So... how can I install the library, do I need git for that? As I said, I'm pretty lost here... Thanks.

Comment: I'll be honest, if you are new to this there's a good amount of knowledge that you'll need to bootstrap, but once you get the basics down it gets much easier. First, [install composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) on your computer, then run `composer --version` from a command line to make sure it is available. If it is not, that needs to be fixed first, ignore WordPress, PHP, everything else. Once installed, `cd` into your plugin and run the `composer require` command that the library suggests. Git is 100% unrelated to this, and although it is a best practice you might want to focus

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas, thanks for the help. Yesterday I managed to install the library with composer via the LocalWP shell. Since LocalWP has composer included, didn't needed to install it on my computer ;) I ran the command 'composer require', but when I enter the package 'sociallydev/spaces-api' doesn't find it... Am I doing something wrong? Does it look into my local folders (in that case would make sense that didn't find it) or online? Thanks!